# SOLVE Hard Equation in real

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

> $$\sqrt { x + \sqrt { 2 x + \sqrt { 4 x + \sqrt { 8 x } } } } = \sqrt { 3 + \sqrt { 3 } }$$

First I squaring an equation but so many bushy of squaring
And then got octic equation is hard to solve...
Can anyone help me ???

Comment: So you want another way to find $x$ without squaring so many times - am I correct?

Comment: Could you write down what equation you got?

Comment: Seems like $x=2$ is a solution.

Comment: I would suggest numerical methods for such an equation.

Comment: @Peter: the sledgehammer is not always the best approach.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Maybe, but this equation appears to be quite complex. Unfortunately, the question does not contain the equation we get after repeated squaring. Surely, there might be a better solution, but if I cannot see an easier way (and here, I would not have an idea to be honest), I tend to apply a method that at least works.

Comment: @peter: by turning the equation to a polynomial one, you introduce many extra solutions and lose the benefit of monotonicity. A general solver would be better. And if you suspect that there is an easy (integer) answer, look for it.

By the way, the octic polynomial is ugly.

Answer (score 2):

The LHS is a monotonic function so that there is at most one solution.

You can suspect an integer solution and try $x=1$ then $x=2$ and bingo !

Alternatively, you can reason as follows:

As the RHS is made of two nested square roots with integers, and the LHS is a quadruple nesting, two unnestings must take place. One could be by the innermost argument $8x$ being a perfect square. Otherwise, two unnestings of the form $\sqrt{a+b\sqrt3}$ will be needed, and $x$ should be a multiple of $3$.

It doesn't take long to realize that $x=2$ has a likely order of magnitude, while $x=3$ or more would be too large. No other number than $2$ is possible.

Answer (score 1):

By $f(x)$ we denote the LHS of the above equation ($x \ge 0$).

Then it is easy to see that $f(2) =\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}}$. Since $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0, \infty)$, the equation $f(x)=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}}$ has the unique solution $x=2.$

Comment: your argument is crystal clear and correct. First you establish uniqueness and then provide a solution, which ensures existence. But the uniqueness holds true for any other positive RHS... In those cases we would actually have to get our hands "dirty" and go through the tedious calculations.

Comment: @PierreCarre: not necessarily. Given the analytical form of the RHS, the number of possible solutions is finite (disregarding known uniqueness).

Comment: @YvesDaoust, I mean that for a general positive RHS (e.g. 33/7), the actual computation of the solution forces you to go through the tedious calculations I mentioned. The current RHS makes it easy to "guess" the solution, but this is not always the case.

Comment: @PierreCarre: such toy problems do have a simple solution. In the real life, either they arise from theoretical studies (e.g. number theory), and remain in the algebraic domain, or they arise from empirical models and are clearly of a numerical nature. In these two cases, the investigation methods will differ.